# Congratulations, you're no longer in Beta!

Tags: discussion

**This site started private beta before July 2012, so it is no longer "beta", it is a full site by our definition**. We've removed the word "beta" from your site banner because we believe that you aren't really a beta site any more, even if you don't get ten questions per day.

[image: Banner that reads "Congratulations" in three-dimensional white text with red, yellow and blue confetti.]

What this means for you:

- the "Beta" is removed from your banner
- the site is moved to the "[Launched](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched)" sites list on Area 51 - which will also remove the A51 info box from the right sidebar
- retain beta reputation levels
- full-site elections will be delayed but will be scheduled eventually

This is the start of a process that we are already discussing internally and will be bringing to the network for public discussion once the plan is finalized. My hope is that this will mean the end of the monolith we currently refer to as "Graduation" in favor of a well-defined set of small targets to achieve the various elements that made up "Graduation".

I'm sure you have many questions, please feel free to ask and I'll answer what I can. It helps me out a lot if you can limit answers to focus on a single question/subject rather than asking a dozen questions in one answer.

Please feel free to [follow the MSE discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta) for more background on this decision. You can ask questions either here or there; I'll try to keep up with all of them. Your mods also have some info, so they may be answering in my stead.

Thanks so much for your patience and stay tuned!

Comment: WOOHOO!!!! Congrats to everyone that has contributed to this success!

Comment: Yay! Much like the Martial Arts SE, I suspect we're still going to be relatively small-time, but still!