# Announcing an upcoming election

Tags: discussion

**Summary**: Physical Fitness Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **August 9**, as your "graduation" election (as a result of [having lost your beta label](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/q/799/15307) a while back).

The timeline:

- On August 2, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on August 9, users can [nominate themselves](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/election/1). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a second Meta post, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- On August 16, if there are four or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for one more week. If at the end of this extension period there are still not four or more candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods) and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to bring the total number of moderators on the site up to 3 (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on August 24 (or on the 31st, if we need to extend the nomination period and only get 4 or more candidates then).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: After having an insufficient number of candidates at the closing of the extension of the nomination period, the election has been cancelled. Graduation elections need to be competitive so four candidates would have need to run. However we did have three candidates so we are treating this a Pro Temp Election and C. Lange has been appointed as a Pro Temp moderating joining Alec and John P. We will try holding a graduation election again in the future.

In the meantime please join me in congratulating C. Lange and thanking them, Alec, and John P. for stepping up and volunteering to serve as moderators for this community.

Comment: Welcome to the team, C!

Comment: As per my comments in the chat, I didn't feel confident enough to put myself forward as a candidate. Knowing now that one more person would have given everyone a legitimate chance, I'm kicking myself a bit.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - People seem to have a real issue with doubting their qualifications. Also, I think people really overestimate how much you need to do as a mod.